# Criei minha entidade em symfony - Crud

Tags: php, symfony-2, crud

Usei o comando:

```
php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud
```

ele gerou todas pagina e controladores no meu projeto, porem quando entro na rota para criar um usuario da o seguinte erro:

```
Expected argument of type "string", "AppBundle\Form\UserType" given
```

Alguém sabe como concertar, ou já aconteceu isso?

Se precisar coloco aqui o codigo, mas é o padrão gerado pelo symfony.3

Comment: Cole o código do controlador gerado, por gentileza.

Comment: Já consegui resolver. Na versão do Symfony  < 2 8 se passava no parâmetro da createForm uma new TypeAbstract agora passa TypeAbstract:class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na versão do Symfony < 2 8 se passava no parâmetro da createForm uma new TypeAbstract agora passa TypeAbstract:class.